# Show a div, only if another div has scroll

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a script (I'm a newbie in JS, level 0), and I'd like to solve it.

**Question:** Is it possible to detect with JS if a div of fixed measurements (340px x 120px), has the overflow triggered when the content exceeds the fixed height ...?

I need to detect the overflow, **only if it is active**, and if that is true, show a hidden div.

**[SEE LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qvjc7a25/4/)** (jsfiddle)

I tried adding the script, but it's an invention that does not work...

Thanks in advance!

```js
var displaced = document.getElementsById('flux')[0];
if (displaced.scrollHeight > displaced.offsetHeight) {

  document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="flux">

    <div id="show">Hello!</div>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br> Consectetuer augue nibh lacus at <br> Pretium Donec felis dolor penatibus <br> Phasellus consequat Vivamus dui lacinia <br><br>

    <!--
        Ornare nonummy laoreet lacus Donec <br>
        Ut ut libero Curabitur id <br>
        Dui pretium hendrerit sapien Pellentesque <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>
        Consectetuer augue nibh lacus at <br>
        Pretium Donec felis dolor penatibus <br><br>
        Phasellus consequat Vivamus dui lacinia <br>
        Ornare nonummy laoreet lacus Donec <br>
        Ut ut libero Curabitur id <br>
        Dui pretium hendrerit sapien Pellentesque <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>
        Consectetuer augue nibh lacus at <br><br>
        Pretium Donec felis dolor penatibus <br>
        Phasellus consequat Vivamus dui lacinia <br>
        Ornare nonummy laoreet lacus Donec <br>
        Ut ut libero Curabitur id <br><br>
        Dui pretium hendrerit sapien Pellentesque <br>
        -->

  </div>
  <!-- // flux -->

</div>
<!-- // container -->

<div id="note">
  Note: The div "show" (red box) must be display = "none".<br>See CSS line 13.<br><br>And it must be display = "block" only if the scroll on the div #flux is present.
</div>
```

Comment: The appropriate function is `getElementById()` and returns only one element, because IDs must be unique to the document.

Comment: Thanks **Heretic Monkey** (a very good observation for an apprentice like me). But it does not work anyway...

Comment: Note that you have to uncomment your CSS property under `#show` that sets `display: none`... This would be easier to diagnose if you included the CSS in your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var displaced = document.getElementsById('flux')[0];` to `document.getElementById('flux')` (`getElementById` returns a single element since `id`s should be unique in the document).
Also, the `display: none` in CSS line 13 was commented out.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/61k3aeh2/) is the corrected fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The only mistake I can see in your code is that you wrote

`var displaced = document.getElementsById('flux')[0];`

Try to change it to

`var displaced = document.getElementById('flux');`

If you change that the demo works perfectly

See the demo fixed:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmnkj197/